# Dual Icon Button in flutter - Prefix and Suffix Icon

Tags: flutter, cross-platform

[image]

I am trying to practice icons and buttons in flutter and I came across this pic with both a prefix and a suffix Icon. I have done this in TextFormField but I do not know how to achieve this for buttons. Please help.

Comment: Following the accepted answer. This is the final code I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This widget is called ListTile, example:

```
       ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        leading: Container(
          child: Icon(Icons.autorenew, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Introduction to Driving",
        ),
        subtitle: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.linear_scale, color: Colors.yellowAccent),
            Text(" Intermediate", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
          ],
        ),
        trailing:
            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0)
       );
```

Comment: I tried this code and removing subtitle worked for me. Thanks for the assistance Abdallah Abdel Aziz. I will post a screenshot and the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer by Abdallah Abdel Aziz.
[image]

This is the final code used

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignUpScreen()));
      },
      child: ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
          leading: Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.black),
          ),
          title: Text(
            "Introduction to Driving",
          ),
          /*subtitle: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
             // Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.black),
              *//*Text(" Intermediate", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))*//*
            ],
          ),*/
          trailing:Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.black, size: 30.0)
      ))
```